# Remove Arch Linux programs installed from the community repository

Tags: arch-linux

I'm wanting to install the multi-threaded release of par2 on my Arch machine. After having successfully installed it running par2 still executes the single threaded version.

`pacsearch par2`
returns:

```
community/libpar2 0.2-7 
    Parity checking library
community/par2cmdline 0.6.11-1 
    A PAR 2.0 compatible file verification and repair tool
```

`pkgfile -s par2`
returns

```
community/par2cmdline
```

Attempting to remove par2cmdline whether referring to it as community/par2cmdline or par2cmdline using `pacman -Rs` returns

```
error: target not found: community/par2cmdline
error: target not found: par2cmdline
```

Any ideas how to identify the correct package names and remove these packages?

Answer (score 1):

According to your search the `par2cmdline` package in not installed on your system. If it was, it would show : `[installed]` on the line.

And `pkgfile` tells you which package in the repositories contains par2, but not which of the packages installed on your system owns the par2 executable in your `$PATH`. To see that use `` pacman -Qo `which par2` ``.

Comment: It returns: /usr/bin/par2 is owned by par2cmdline 0.6.14-2.